# How to transfer value from List between forms?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have `List<Basket> sas = new List<Basket>();` in Form1.
And i need to output all values from this List in another form.

Edited: Now i have problem with outputing.

```
    List<Basket> sas = new List<Basket>();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        foreach(Basket e in sas)
        {
            basketBox.Text += e.Name + Environment.NewLine;
        }
    }
```

I added elements in Form2, but when I try to output them in Form1 nothing happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways:

You can have the list as a static (global) variable in the form1 class and then use it in the other form.

Another solution would be to have a context class to be given to the other form when you construct it.

Answer (score 1):

if by from you mean windows forms, then you can simply make your list `public static`, so you can have access to it everywhere.
If you are working with ASP.NET web forms then you probably should relay on your database.

---

PS: you can use the Singelton pattern or DI as well. but for the sake of simplicity stick  with statics